# As of July 2018, does my SAAS App need to support IE 11?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, saas

I appreciate this is a highly opinionated question. The issue: while IE 11 usage lowers, IE Support becomes more difficult. Is it time to take it off life support?

The option: Simply say "We don't support IE, try something better" on the home page.

The downside: Some people still hang on to IE 11 and so there is going to be some percentage of loss of use.

It seems to me, that if my site were a consumer based site, mainly for viewing purposes, then still supporting IE would be the rational thing to do. Because if someone surfs to a page, and it says "No IE Support" they will simply leave for one of many other similar sites.

But, a browser app is a different thing.  It's a business app (Project Management) and I doubt there are any end users who ONLY have access to IE 11 and would thus be unable to use it at all.

But I think that most such users even if they typically use IE 11, ALSO have a second browser installed for such times when a site is not supported in IE, or it just doesn't work well in IE. (Like that every happens, right?)

In support of this is Gist.run which does not run on IE 11 (just tried it, Promise is not polyfilled.)

As a startup, I don't want to spend time/money supporting IE 11 if I don't have to.  I have been supporting it, and I would like to drop it if feasible.

NetMarketshare.com says IE 11 usage is at 12.14 while w3Counter says it's at 2.71. Who to believe?

So my question is: Will I actually lose potential users by not supporting IE 11? If so, is the percentage low enough that it does not make financial sense to support it?

I am sure the question will arise, "So how many IE users do you currently have?" The answer is zero, as there have been enough issues in IE to make it an unpleasant experience.

In thinking about this, it seems to me that I can simply pull the plug on IE, and see if there are any complaints or requests for IE support. I would rather not support it at all, then support it half-baked which just makes the app look bad to end users who don't realize it's an IE 11 problem, not an app problem.

Comment: I use feature detection instead of UserAgent sniffing. IE11 is my baseline browser and I use a test suite of various webkit and gecko browsers. IE11 has some security features (ActiveX filtering, tracking protection) + It uses a security zone model that other web browsers don't. MS is encouraging non-Enterprise users to switch to other browsers because IE has too many dials and knobs. Home editions of windows (OEM) tend to include unwanted fluff ware and tracking software that enterprise users don't endure in managed environments. Many enterprise http apps still have ActiveX dependencies.

Comment: short: It depends on your target market(s). Home or Enterprise, High speed internet is not globally available, nor is it universally available in the first world. Usage statistics use server side UAS matching, It has always been known that the broad use of UA sniffing could lead to spurious usage stats. IE is not widely used on tablet or mobile platforms. You could use your own server logs to monitor UA usage and geo trends for your products. where I am sitting right now.. its wall to wall Win7 desktops. (400 seats)… support for IE extends to the EOL of its OS.I expect that winX will continue.

Comment: Thanks Rob, great point on Monitoring Usage to see what it actually is for my site - and then making the decision from there. If you want to post as answer, I will accept.

Comment: HI Greg, thanks for the positive reply... I don't think there can be one definitive answer to your question... you are at your own coal face. (tunnel vision, focused on the task at hand). I do think though it is unwise to not test in IE11. You should be using feature testing in your scripting and vendor prefixes in your css regardless. Many frameworks already include libraries that include poly-fills and workarounds browser vendor quirks. I would like to share a good read (probably not relevant to your question, but a valuable dev resource: following...

Comment: "Web Style Guide" by "Patrick J Lynch and Sarah Horton". Yale University Press. ISBN: 978-0-300-21165-8... In my mind, the process of web development comes down to re-use of common design patterns. You do however need to draw a line for a base level browser that supports some of the HTML5 design patterns. eg. IE11 renders <main> as an inline element, but you can add modernizer.js to your projects to tweak IE11 to render it as a block element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether you need to support IE depends on who your users are. Do they use IE?
And with "users" i do not mean your current users, but your target users.

- Who are you targeting?
  Is your software a *B2B software that's used by companies* or a *B2C software that's used by consumers*?

For **consumers**, i think as of mid 2018 I think it's fair to assume they do not use IE.
For **companies**, that still depends on what kind of companies. Small or young companies and startups likely use Firefox or Chrome, but bigger companies ("enterprises", more than 1000 employees) still use IE, as far as I see the situation today.

So to make the decision whether to support IE (which for sure is extra effort in development) you need to know who you're targeting.